# String variable that is imported from a file

Tags: java

I had imported a sentence from a file and stored it in String. For example

> (i am a football player)

stored in String `s`. I need to print it output like

> ("i am a football player")

so the quotes must be added. I used `StringBuilder` to add quotes by using `append`.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: did you escape the quotes when you appended them ? like `append('\"');`

Comment: yeah manos .u got it .but when i tried to add the quotes by using append function .it returns a single "

Comment: Are the parenthese part of the string? If not, then please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

SO here is the solution for your query.

```
String s = "(I am a Football player)";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(s);
sb.insert(1,"\"");
sb.insert(sb.length()-1,"\"");
System.out.println(sb);//("I am a Football player")
```

You must use append and insert properly.

Answer (score 0):

To add a quote you need to escape it.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("I am not a football Player");
s.insert(0, "\"");//to tell that's not the closing quote using a \
s.append("\"");
```

---

Or Use single quotes.

```
s.append('"');
```